# ruby - how to parse this LinkedIn's hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, hash, linkedin-api

From LinkedIn API I got this hash:

```
> #<LinkedIn::Mash all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash api_standard_profile_request=#<LinkedIn::Mash headers=#<LinkedIn::Mash
> all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash name="x-li-auth-token" value="name:_nNI">]
> total=1> url="http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/asdasfga">
> first_name="first name" headline="job position"
> id="id of user" industry="industry"
> last_name="last name" location=#<LinkedIn::Mash
> country=#<LinkedIn::Mash code="en"> name="country">
> site_standard_profile_request=#<LinkedIn::Mash
> url="http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=key_number&authToken=_nNI&authType=name&trk=api*a_12346*s_12346*">>]
> total=1>
```

Already long time I try to get the `first_name`, `url` and `country`, but still I can't parse it.
Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** attempts:

```
linkedin.connections.each do |item|
   puts item
end
```

gives

```
total
1
all
#<LinkedIn::Mash api_standard_profile_request=#<LinkedIn::Mash headers=#<LinkedIn::Mash all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash name=...
```

When I tried

```
linkedin.connections.api_standard_profile_request.each do |item|
   puts item
end
```

then I got

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: check out please the updated post. I don't know how to go into the `api_standard_profile_request` hash.

Comment: What sort of object is `linkedin.connections`? Is that the object you printed at the beginning of the question?

Comment: You can just call `.to_hash` to turn a Mash into a Hash (like params).

`linkedin.to_hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
linkedin.all.each do |profile|
  puts profile.first_name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest that you debug objects with `p` instead of `puts`. It calls `inspect` on the object you're printing rather than `to_s`, which gives you a lot more info about the object.

Next, check out the documentation on [`Hashie::Mash`](http://rubydoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/master/Hashie/Mash). Your `LinkedIn::Mash` object is inheriting from this class, but LinkedIn isn't providing much documentation, so you'll have to go up the inheritance chain.

Since `Hashie::Mash` is a hash-like object, you should use `each_pair` when iterating over it to get each key-value pair in the hash rather than one key or value at a time:

```
linkedin.connections.each_pair do |key, value|
  p key
  p value
end
```

None of that really answers your question, but hopefully you can get some more information from your debugging efforts. I'm guessing you need to do something like this:

```
linkedin.connections[0].url
```

but I'm not positive.